# FreeRADIUS fails to start

Tags: linux, centos, freeradius

I don't remember exactly what I changed, but I think I replaced the current Freeradius `users` file with one from a backup and I guess permissions got messed up somehow.

I get this written to the logs when I try to start the radiusd service (`/etc/init.d/radiusd start`):

```
Thu Feb 20 08:37:21 2014 : Error: Couldn't open /etc/raddb/users for reading: Permission denied
Thu Feb 20 08:37:21 2014 : Error: Errors reading /etc/raddb/users
Thu Feb 20 08:37:21 2014 : Error: /etc/raddb/modules/files[7]: Instantiation failed for module "files"
Thu Feb 20 08:37:21 2014 : Error: /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[10]: Failed to load module "files".
Thu Feb 20 08:37:21 2014 : Error: /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[1]: Errors parsing authorize section.
Thu Feb 20 08:37:21 2014 : Error: Failed to load virtual server <default>
```

Output from `ls -la /etc/raddb/`

```
# ls -lah /etc/raddb/
total 328K
drwxr-xr-x.   8 root radiusd 4.0K Feb 20 08:28 .
drwxr-xr-x. 120 root root     12K Feb 20 08:32 ..
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd  671 Oct  3  2012 acct_users
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 4.1K Oct  3  2012 attrs
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd  513 Oct  3  2012 attrs.access_challenge
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd  481 Oct  3  2012 attrs.access_reject
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd  437 Oct  3  2012 attrs.accounting_response
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 2.0K Oct  3  2012 attrs.pre-proxy
drwxrwx---.   2 root radiusd 4.0K Jun 13  2013 certs
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 7.2K Feb  6 14:12 clients.conf
-rw-r--r--.   1 root radiusd 1.3K Oct  3  2012 dictionary
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd  21K Jun 14  2013 eap.conf
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 4.8K Oct  3  2012 example.pl
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 2.3K Oct  3  2012 hints
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 1.6K Oct  3  2012 huntgroups
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 3.2K Oct  3  2012 ldap.attrmap
drwxr-x---.   2 root radiusd 4.0K Dec 19 14:05 modules
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 4.2K Oct  3  2012 policy.conf
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 4.8K Oct  3  2012 policy.txt
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd  984 Oct  3  2012 preproxy_users
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd  27K Oct  3  2012 proxy.conf
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd  28K Oct  3  2012 radiusd.conf
drwxr-x---.   2 root radiusd 4.0K Feb 20 08:38 sites-available
drwxr-x---.   2 root radiusd 4.0K Jun 13  2013 sites-enabled
drwxr-x---.   4 root radiusd 4.0K Dec 17 14:02 sql
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 3.0K Dec 17 14:21 sql.conf
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 2.5K Oct  3  2012 sqlippool.conf
-rw-r-----.   1 root radiusd 3.6K Oct  3  2012 templates.conf
-rw-r--r--.   1 root radiusd  30K Feb  7 11:53 users
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root    4.0K Nov 26 13:57 webmgmt
```

**Additional info:**

I am running CentOS 6.5.

I am able to start the radiusd service in debug mode (`radiusd -X`) and it works just fine. (Maybe because it reads config files as the `root` or something...

Maybe you can point me in the right direction, because I am kind of confused, it seems `radiusd` user HAS permissions for reading that file. I tried all kinds of combinations of chmod'ding the file, but no success. Tried changing the owner of `users` file to `radiusd` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Run FreeRadius as su user. You have permission problems. Maybe use chmod to change the permission of the users file. But it would be a security threat.

Run `freeradius -X` as root
 or `radiusd -X` as root

Comment: As I said I tried CHModding. Also always running freeradius in a debug mode kinda makes no sense...

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. Guess this is related to the dependencies of free-radius. Upgrade your Ubuntu environment:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install freeradius
```

Also, need to have root permissions to run this. Not sure, but it worked for me once I started freeradius under root user. Command to do that:

> systemctl status freeradius

HTH